# Android http client fails to connect over time

Tags: android, http, xamarin, https, httpclient

I have a problem in my xamarin android application. It sends requests to the server let us say every 5 minutes, and after 40-50 minutes being passed it fails.

I used internet connectivity plugin for xamarin to listen to internet disconnection, but it didn't trigger.

Here's exception stacktrace:

```
failed to connect to  from  after 120000ms
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0 
  at Java.Net.HttpURLConnectionInvoker.Connect () [0x0000a] in <95d915721ad748108ff096dce8f8f32c>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0 () [0x0005a] in <95d915721ad748108ff096dce8f8f32c>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<DoProcessRequest>d__45.MoveNext () [0x0012e] in <95d915721ad748108ff096dce8f8f32c>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__40.MoveNext () [0x00230] in <95d915721ad748108ff096dce8f8f32c>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <25ebe1083eaf4329b5adfdd5bbb7aa57>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at MyProject.Services.Helpers.HttpHelper+<GetAsync>d__20.MoveNext () [0x00066] in <a7ae1820966b4814b52c3da64fea6a88>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at MyProject.Services.Helpers.HttpHelper+<ExecuteGetAsync>d__14.MoveNext () [0x000f0] in <a7ae1820966b4814b52c3da64fea6a88>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at MyProject.Services.Helpers.HttpHelper+<Get>d__8`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00075] in <a7ae1820966b4814b52c3da64fea6a88>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at MyProject.Services.Providers.AuthenticationProvider+<IsTwoFactorAuthenticationEnabled>d__2.MoveNext () [0x00077] in <a7ae1820966b4814b52c3da64fea6a88>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at MyProject.Services.Services.AuthenticationService+<IsTwoFactorAuthenticationEnabled>d__7.MoveNext () [0x0006d] in <a7ae1820966b4814b52c3da64fea6a88>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at MyProject.Core.ViewModels.Base.BaseViewModel+<Execute>d__25`1[TOut].MoveNext () [0x000a2] in <8cda1c2cffb84419929f531e828b43bf>:0 
  --- End of managed Java.Net.SocketTimeoutException stack trace ---
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to   after 120000ms
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:357)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:201)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:183)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:145)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:141)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps to find the question:

1.Check whether you can connect directly through URL, using any of browser instead of Android app.

2.If it fails, then it could be an issue with network connectivity not with android code.

3.Then check whether the mobile and Computer are connected to same network

4.One of the reason behind Network connection failure is "FireWall" option, which might be blocking connection request.

After checking that, you can try to connect through code as well direct through browser.